# How to change childNodes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, clone

how can I clone the table and automatic increase the `#changeThis` number when I click the button?

This is my example of problem

```
<button type="button" onclick="cloneTable()">clone Table</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id="changeThis">1</th>
    <td><select name="" size="1"><option></option></select><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you

Comment: did u try anything?

Comment: Pls read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a query in stackoverflow

Comment: i dont think so@Manish just copy paste his HW :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `cloneNode` method.

```js
var i=1;
function cloneTable(){
   var table = document.getElementById("table1");
   var clone = table.cloneNode(true);
   clone.id="table"+ ++i;
   document.body.appendChild(clone);
   document.querySelector('#table' +i+' th ').innerHTML=i;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="cloneTable()">clone Table</button>
<table id="table1"><tr><th class="changeThis">1</th><td><select name="" size="1"><option></option></select><input type="text" ></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: i think you got it wrong he wants the `#changeThis` id of th to be changed and not the table. Because according to your logic still there will be multiple th with same id thus violating the standards.

Comment: @Manish, have a look at my answer now.

Comment: @Fun, don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people.